# Docusign, pre-filling template, text and radio confusion - general data tab?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the ruby_gem to pre-fill a Docusign template in embedded signing. I currently have mostly textLabels, 1 radio and a couple of checkboxes.

It just dawned on me that to proper pre-fill the values on docusign, I have to tie the docusign data model to to match Docusigns...

What I'm trying to do

```
signer = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new({
  clientUserId: form["user_id"],
  email: form["email"],
  name: form["full_name"],
  roleName: 'signer',
  tabs: {
    "textTabs" => form.map { |k, v|  { "tabLabel" => k, "value" => v } },
   },
})
```

Now what I was hoping, was that I could simply call out the tabLabel, and have the value passed along. So textTabs is obvious, for radio buttons, simply select the value passed along, and for checkboxes, my data will say `true/false`

However, radioButtons do not get the value, because as I can tell from the documentation, I have to add a secondary tap style, called `radio_group_tabs`? And I imagine it's the same story with checkboxes...which means, I have to to tie my data model to that of docusigns, or at least build some middleware to pluck radio data, and checkbox data...which really now, docusigns API is bleeding into my code like nothing else.

Is there ANY way around this? What I want seems simple. Declare the tabLabel, assign the value

Answer (score 0):

radio buttons are part of a group, because their logic dictates that. You don't want someone to be able to pick more than one, but how do you know which ones they can or cannot pitck?

Checkboxes are not like that, but their value is not what you are looking for, you need to either have them checked or not.

So, no, if you're looking for DocuSign object model to be like that of HTML DOM, it's not the case, you do have to work out the differences.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...how could a signer pick more than 1 radio button in a group?

radio group name: 'test'
test => 'option_1'


so the appropriate option is selected, due to the val matching. If the option doesn't exist, the radio buttons are all blank.


Should be noted, these are read only radio buttons

Comment: They cannot. The issue here is the radio buttons have to be part of a group, unlike checkboxes that do not need to be part of a group.

Comment: Question, because you seem knowledgable on the topic - I've created a system since asking the question to take care of the above, but having issues filling in the group data.

object I'm sending, `radioGroupTabs=>[{groupName: "selection-type", value: "bank"}]}}`. It's not populating however, thoughts?

Comment: this is the group, you also need to create the radioTabs separately, did you do that?